# Body response truncated with Retrofit android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get a whole PDF with retrofit on Android. But at the moment to get the response it's incomplete.

```
private void getDocument(String option) {
    Call<String> auth = apiInterface.getDocument(token, option);
    auth.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            //String responseFinal = bodyToString(response.body());
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //Response success. Handle data here
                Log.v("getDocument", response.body());
                base64PDF = response.body();
            }
            else{
                //For getting error message
                Log.d("Error message",response.raw().message());
                //For getting error code. Code is integer value like 200,404 etc
                Log.d("Error code",String.valueOf(response.raw().code()));
            }
     }
}
```

I got a lot of logs due to the HttpLoggingInterceptor:

```
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZUdyYXkvU3VidHlwZS9JbWFnZS9IZWlnaHQgMjkwL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvV2lkdGggMTA4My9MZW5ndGggMTkwNDMvQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4Pj5zdHJlYW0KeJztXeGhqyoMPht0BEfoCIzQERihIzBCR2CEjsAIHcEROoLvoKIBAgkUq+ddvz/39oghBPgICerPz4kTJ06cOHHixD8FAXHZW5sTJ04cGFch1cOY14ChN0aruxB7K3nixInD4CJ+KaNHGSPG+5dCbt3eKp84cWJXdDdl3kzS8GAe8rq38idOnNgD4v6sYg3AH+qMg5w48U/hen9+xhoLXuqMf5w48U/gctMfehsB3k95Bj9OnPh/4yJbuRs+XveTPU6c+L9iK9442ePEif8xblvyxswe8gybnjjxv0L3aBvfSEKfUdMTJ/43kOY7vDGiv5+ux4kT/wN06ksOx4qbq/uiaCxuyhW/vo/VTpz4x9Hpb/PG76bFVX7BH4jx8HI+yjXBcDsZ7sSJfxnCNOUEHp5L9ZouTDLHSR0nTnwbuxDHSgY/qqBwl9xV7WS8Eyf+VexDHIA5ZEHhzNZmJ/OdOPFv4mqakUER3ssDtVe6MIc5Tuo4ceJ72CM4OgIwB53XYTHHSR0nTnwLl++nYx3WtCydXHkvW5ts2X1seOLEvwfZtyKCYshFCUOWXR0UnS1XbYeH+QSPzzoBhf5Io/PdSnlcS4y5t7JHxF5BDov1+JYmy3KZo546zGeNaf8wn/hMofOIfx5F5t1b2ePhoj4bnh9hOQr2cyfLspljN+po73ZQLSVwUkceosSYeyt7OIj+s9H5EdajYJIsuzKHoopWG8N81px360dxLp/pc1IHAVFizL2VPRgujw8H50dYD3TQyZWVOSQpt9ocLtbRVzZI0lUUgXbFcJyxDh6uiQ+BoNhb2WNhV5cDMMelKXO06OS6V7H2DWqG6MtVeJ0vji5DJ5lvz9xb0SNhX5cDsAGdli1ijkadXJOwbrtDuBXXr8/XrlWA19N7a3kgXAuctQ2wssEPucCvZQVHdCsLdcWeh6aFFqC0+te5QalEx5gLe+t4HNTuo1thOQpGpxGKDpwOLTtZlraq5arfFdb9Oncq1Ug/S7nBqPrbuGz/2tE81oiipIqWMkfLTiaVC9DyNUOqrOo/wBzdcY9W0R29t4YHwbUvnBKtsU4xQRUtZo6mnazK2vVuWHVhqOUP7FaerXunHehI/d4aHgNytydWZqwxAZIOQDS1Z0pvaitupTPa5WdlWcVtwyybQLTvnXYg3fC9FTwEdNmgbI91mNN0UJCHcWhqrMKY0KtZxaas4j+QW3m17512IPt5bwUPgEvhmGwPcKCDpAPJL7qgqblEYeNa5We7smrbUdZmkBv0TjuQ/by3gvtj9zAHjOdpqmwNczTu5MLWtdo4rIduWLvLLR7bbQsXTdhbjxS+O6r+IMTeYY7hvbrWiiq7Rg4KMkKNF+Deye3TVUK02TmsYTtjOLUe/wsSetZ0bz1SoCy8t357Q/KG/4YAR8FIZVbm0PwKno2TlMYJZkY92kzi1Ta8r2kd/kk34TTdW5EUKLd2b/12xt7nwAY4xslXkVYxR/NMg1k0N+laAdrkZ1+rOFa1h6eO3mm6tyIpUGbeW799oVljf1OsdECmZY/BHGvlQpY2sR4rrSoedRz9VIdaNN1bkxQoM++t367QhHG+gPuiDBn3LDhvislvBuVkC+YZjxaxFr1I63jU0aDOLXE9vqaUmffWb09owjZfAPAJDFG0ijlavzDDQjnhgnu09PPNw/qOH8084NGgoVvidXxNKTPvrd+O0LxxvyU0X5vDMAekDvq0ctjMSqwxKfG/oI7HH9CUegXF3vrthpJzEVsBHOig4rU1zPHeZr+vnHzBpt+Pczy9k2RfHmQ4VTZo6HYQf0FThRv28HpvjmMxhySKFgRTF2zEHB51dDxVPs3PCs8QhlNli5ZuBd9Z21ubFFTCskfXe2to3pjfEuAoGMUHNczRb5VjUK4GG8IwPF0+rHI5/za+KJlVZ4OGbgbzJzRVqF2Pr/fG0KwRvymAU0CFDGqYAzwX8/xpCuWqsNTBfOffZ0GXbpEzHi83nBpbtHQjqL+hqcLM+gf03haaN+A3xZp2oMIua5SR8e6mGd4TdW2Np7wW9Cx1PnufzVLjdKjdcGps0NCNIP6Ipgqx6l/Qe1No1nDfFmAdJh5HAU/kswM0T+9Z3LbWU66SkTqY53E/2j31TsrEQIZTYYOGboOI/vdWKAWFmfUP6L0lJG+0bwrAHDpfsoY5gnvamk+5Wkbq+EJ+Vi5Spve3Gk6FLVq6BeJO3FujFBRi1b+g94aQhEm+Ac1WpwFzbEodX8jPGiejD37n0KChmyA2194apaAiTf+G3tuBfMjsCwDMIdgl2cwRHW5va0Dl6pmoo+MpVZ+fXSuYG2Y49bVo6QZQf0bTkzpC8HMU2+HFVqfguOkCkI+Z2aatBZWraA70GpZW9fnZ9VTjpaDCBg3dAPLPaHpSR4iDHSIlXkX6IXM4WmprQuVqmqlj4/zsGkxx1jCc6lq0tDlQj3dvpVJQmLJ/QO+twBp22wJ8/50gsgrmeIPXfyxzrq0JlRPrqupZmtXmZ+UiwWVpDKe6Bg1tDtzF3FurFBSm7B/QeyPs+1XZEfB8uM6WBMyhyoWDcdrWhosujjq2zc8u7Lpwj+HU1qChrZE4lbO3WikoVNvj670NJG+Qbwowg1S2ID8LswBnjq2pY9P87OrjLzsew6mtRUvbIuVi7q1XCgpX9/B6b4IjhEjBll9mC1YwBwiieE1ta0XlxC57I81Tryo/u8he31NoOJU1aGhbJDeneyuWgkroe3S9t8ARQqSAOfJZ4s+Yw/+cXVszKid2oY6Op1/NG8vWd/ys2V3DqaxFS1siPfj21iwFlVL44HpvAc0ZctsCEELeBeKf/Fhgks/wtzWjcmLXiKxhKViTn13jKOtzxqzaGjS0JTLL1t6qpaCSGh9b7w0gOSNuWwBCyLtA/JMfmGwZXGprR+XErtTBzM/eyivrkeYZTl0NGtoQud7eW7cUVFrlQ+vdHgcIdMD3+5pswUTQIoPcBqetIZUTu1LHZvlZsdwLKjOcuho0tB2y68TeyqWgMjofWe/22D/QAQghv3mqYA5wzltGF9saUjmxYDYz87NdWiqO5aFiuNkxnKoaNLQZ8h7m3tqloHJKH1jv5qAMsT3AUbD8VIOnTZnMkc/bbGRJQB0b5Wc7rIF/jjqIrxrvrV4KKqv1cfVuDcEZbpsCHgWTuYIv9mnTBcQj/G1NqZxYQB3MEPS7MD+r0BsNp6oWLW0DynHcW78UVF7tw+rdGMSzIl8AZI7sYCpnDnD4HJ/CbW2pnFhIHR3PCoX52d7d57krhlNTg4ZaXIVS6mmMeSglqs7DSsoha6SphRD3WV3z/P3PTRTvEAFUU73F7Vchq5hSd4GvILZE7ZNOMy7AAnq0wMcv49//ADqwSda7r2AO8mT7p9bzoZxYSB3Uq85mlOVn5XKfNwUMp6bP23mRj6gDjCqlDzoK9LmmvxBK42Yxj1vl7FGt9L5IHRqyf8qI1cZz+rVPOv2Sxi9hYGq+jaq1gIUg+29rQObIMQIMpfJmI+OZmHrDYVBOrEcdgmeHovyscXcZ/M85fNjI7p7qpfejhD0SPdJQ05/LLaY4H697jfeh2ugtU8P4Jf0ZPTaiijo6qfu8rqbKAotWe+IBlMkxAjsJU3RHpdUSUE6sRx0b5Ge75S6fcAynoo+aKPKsbQQtYsSFo6pKgVNDmuIClct3AqqBhS8q52G/NZjQ08agnDquFHHOeHI7zQNlhM0Bt+o6U+4j5rgk76ixGcOafl9Ilr4l+dlllxlscwynng8aKHtSOo88iNTKx03g8saIvpQ81Kfq
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
12-05 15:52:52.931 4054-6365/com.dummy.myapp D/OkHttp: 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
```

And on my own Log i got only this:

```
V/getDocument: JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZUdyYXkvU3VidHlwZS9JbWFnZS9IZWlnaHQgMjkwL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvV2lkdGggMTA4My9MZW5ndGggMTkwNDMvQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4Pj5zdHJlYW0KeJztXeGhqyoMPht0BEfoCIzQERihIzBCR2CEjsAIHcEROoLvoKIBAgkUq+ddvz
```

Which is the first part of the Logs shown before.

Any ideas? I'm stucked.

Comment: I tried below answering, but problem is same https://stackoverflow.com/q/58615323/7639056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I just added the next.

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
```

and

```
addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

to

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If logcat is capping the length at 1000 then you can split the string you want to log with String.subString() and log it in pieces. For example:

```
int maxLogSize = 1000; 
for(int i = 0; i <= veryLongString.length() / maxLogSize; i++) { 
int start = i * maxLogSize; int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize; 
end = end > veryLongString.length() ? veryLongString.length() : end; 
Log.v(TAG, veryLongString.substring(start, end)); 
}
```